# Adding a memoization with fix?

Tags: haskell, memoization

Trying to solve a task calculating count of combinations (with repetition) which meet some predicate, like equality of elements sum to a given number:

```
countChange :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
countChange n xs = fromIntegral . length $ filter ((== n) . sum) $
                        concatMap (comb xs) [1..n]
    where
    comb _ 0    = [[]]
    comb xs k   = [y:ys | l@(y:xs') <- tails xs, ys <- comb l (k-1)]
```

Above naive approach has a significant performance issue with recursive call of `comb` recalculating k-1 combinations repeatedly.

I'd like to add a memoization of results by use of least fixed point, ie. by `Data.Function.fix` .
I've added a declaration for a self-recursive function, however loosing ideas how implement `memoize` function:

```
countChange :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
countChange n xs = fromIntegral . length $ filter ((== n) . sum) $
                        concatMap (fix (memoize . comb) xs) [1..n]
    where
    comb _ _ 0    = [[]]
    comb xs f k   = [y:ys | l@(y:xs') <- tails xs, ys <- f (fix (memoize . comb) l (k-1))]
    memoize f     = undefined  -- ??
```

Can you put some advice how to solve the implementation or is my idea quite wrong ?

Comment: Are you playing on CodeWars?

Comment: @Arnon Yep but that's my extended challenge. Already wrote memoization with `Data.Map` but curious how to do it by fixed point function.

Comment: Because the solution to this kata is very simple if you treat it mathematically instead of programatically. I think that the mathematical solution is what they were aiming for. It doesn't require any memoization.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to make memoization automatic with recursion, you have to do it in the recursive combinator itself because each recursive call has to share the "memory" (ie where you store the memoized values).

For exemple, with the fibonacci sequence you should write something like

```
fibo' _ 0 = 1
fibo' _ 1 = 1
fibo' f n = f (n - 1) + f (n - 2)

fibo = memoizingFix fibo'
```

Where memoizingFix depends on which function you want to memoize. The most general way is probably keeping a Data.Map in a State Monad but you may want to use more efficient data Structures that are less general (for example a mutable array).

One last thing, when implementing Your memoizeFix combinator, keep in mind whether you want to store values from one call to another or just in the current recursion. (ie : If I run `fibo hugeValue` then `fibo (hugeValue + 1)` will the second call be nearly as long as the first or nearly immediate ?)

(Note : I voluntarily didn't give you the memoizeFix combinator as it seems you 're willing to understood things and find by yourself, but feel free to ask for it - or even google it, it's nearly everywhere on the Internet - if you need.)